# How to edit crontab through php script?

Tags: php, shell, cron

I have a function which writes into the crontab using PHP script:

```
function changejob() {
global $existingJobs;
global $newJob;
chmod("/tmp/crontab", 0764);   
if (file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab', $newJob.PHP_EOL)) {
    if (exec('crontab /tmp/crontab')) { 
        echo 'Crontab changed to ' .$newJob;    
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error with exec command';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'file_put_input function failed';
}
```

}

The script echoes 'Error with exec command'. 
If I immediately then run crontab /tmp/crontab in the command line, the crontab file is edited correctly. So I know the file_put_contents function worked and the echo exec() function did not.

Error reporting is enabled, but nothing was reported.

Comment: `echo` inside an `if` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I tried without the echo and it still returned the 'Error with exec command'

Comment: How do you run this script? Using the CLI or as a web page?

Comment: I run from a webpage

Comment: There are a handful of reasons it fails. Starting with not being able to find `crontab`. For other reasons type `man crontab` on your system and carefully read the first 4-5 paragraphs of text.

Comment: I will try that thankyou, how come it can find crontab for file_put_contents? Assuming it needs to be found to run that function? I am very new to php and trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: The destination file for file_put_contents() is a fully qualified filename, so it can always be "found". The exec call to crontab assumes crontab is in the path, when in fact it is probably not. You should fully qualify the path to the crontab executable. And then you'll have to deal with any permission issues with having the web server execute crontab.

Comment: How does one fully qualify the path to the crontab executable? Is there any error reporting I can use? So I can systematically go through the reasons for failure.